# is it possible to compare string in c just by using stdio.h and conio.h header?

Tags: c

I've tried all ideas of me but all of it doesn't work. I just make a program that when the user type EXIT then the program will exit also just by using two header. The `#include<stdio.h>` and the `#include<conio.h>`.

Comment: Have you tried *iteration* ? No headers involved.

Comment: `<conio.h>` isn't even a standard C header.

Comment: `strcmp` is implemented as a loop.  You could write that yourself.

Comment: You could reimplement pretty much all of `<string.h>` by hand if you're bored.

Comment: and you should show what you have tried

Comment: If you show the code for some of your attempts, someone could find the issue in that code and help you - so please do that instead of just presenting a problem and hope someone writes tall the code for you.

Comment: You can use a state machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own strcmp.

like this :

```
int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (s1[i] != '\0' || s2[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (s2[i] != s1[i])
            return (s1[i] - s2[i]);
        i++;
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: And s1 and s2 are not `null_ptr` or assert this.  And the whole `strcmp` is evil thing explained.  This is why we can't have nice things security comment and such. :)

Comment: @MichaelDorgan The standard lib `strcmp()` does not require a test for `s1, s2` 
 as `NULL`.

Comment: 1) `return (s1[i] - s2[i]);` is not correct when `s1[i] < 0` (should be an `unsigned char` compare.) 2)  `int i;` --> `size_t i;`.